# How to estimate (compute) Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$$f(x)= \frac{\sin \pi x}{x (x^{2}-1)}$$ for $x\in \mathbb R - \{ 0, -1, 1 \}$ and $f(x):= \pi $ for $x=0$ and $f(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x= -1, 1$.

Clearly, $f\in C_{0}(\mathbb R) $ and 
note that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| (1+|x|) dx < \infty.$

**My questions are**:

(1) How to compute the Fourier transform  $\hat{f}$ of the $f$ (as defined above), that is, for $\xi \in \mathbb R$,
$\hat {f}(\xi)= \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx = $ ? Or, even without computation can we conclude that that,  $\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\hat{f}(\xi)| d\xi < \infty $ ?

(2) Define $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x):= |f(x)|$ , for $x\in \mathbb R$. Is it true that $\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\hat{g}(\xi)| d\xi < \infty $ ?

(**Motivation**:
Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$ such that $ab> 1$ ; put

$$L^{1}_{a}(\mathbb R)= \{ f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C  \ \text {measurable} : ||(1+|x|)^{a}f||_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}< \infty \},$$
and
$$FL^{1}_{b}(\mathbb R)= \{ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C \ \text {measurable} : ||(1+|w|)^{b} \hat {f}||_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}< \infty \}.$$
We consider a Foureier-Lebsgue space,
$$FL:=L^{1}_{a}(\mathbb R) \cap FL^{1}_{b}(\mathbb R).$$
The question is: If  $f\in FL$. Can we expect   $|f|\in FL$  ?; so, my motivation here is that above example serve here as a counter example. )

---

Thanks to math fraternity;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use partial fractions, and the fact that you know the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x$, and also if you know the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, then it is easy to obtain the Fourier transforms of $f(x+1)$ and $f(x-1)$.  I think you will get something compactly supported with Lipschitz derivative.

$g = |f|$ is harder.  We will outline a proof $\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\hat{g}(\xi)| d\xi = \infty $.  Since the Fourier transform of $f$ is very nice, we will instead work with $h = \frac12(f+g) = f_+$.  It is sufficient to show $\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\hat{h}(\xi)| d\xi = \infty $.

Find a smooth bump function $\phi$, supported on $[-3,3]$, such that $\phi(x) h(x) = \sin(\pi x) I_{|x|<2}$.  We can compute $\widehat{\phi h}(\xi)$ explicitly, seeing that it is something like an oscillating function that decays like $|\xi|^{-2}$.  Hence $\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\widehat{\phi h}(\xi)| d\xi = \infty $.

However, $\widehat{\phi h} = \hat\phi*\hat h$, where $*$ denotes convolution.  Since $\hat\phi$ is localized, we can make some approximations when $\xi$ is large, and see that
$\int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\widehat{\phi h}(\xi)| d\xi \le C \int_{\mathbb R} (1+|\xi|)^{2} |\hat{h}(\xi)| d\xi $.  I hope that you are satisfied with proving this last bit yourself, because it is probably going to be a bit fiddly.

Comment: As for the Fourier transform of $|f|$, that looks quite a bit harder.  My wife is calling me to bed, so maybe I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot prof. S M, ; and hope to see you tomorrow;

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{\sin(\pi\,x)}{x(1-x^2)}=\frac{\sin(\pi\,x)}{x}+\frac{\sin(\pi(x+1))}{2(x+1)}+\frac{\sin(\pi(x-1))}{2(x-1)}.$$

The first summand is a multiple of the [sinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function and its Fourier transform is given in the link.  Use shift the shift property of the Fourier transform to compute the transform of the other two summands.